# Syntax error on string to int java

Tags: java, random, input, typeconverter

I am new to Java and I get confused here.  Why do I get an error when I want to convert string to int in java?

If I type in msi(a to e), and I want to use msii variable inside if statement to outside, and I can't, so I try using `sout` outside.  But I get an error.

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner i=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Name\t\t\t");
    String nama=i.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Nim\t\t\t");
    String nim=i.nextLine();
    System.out.println("grade\t\t");
    String msi=i.next();
    switch(msi) {
        case "a||A":
            {
                msii=Integer.parseInt(msi);
                msii=4;
                break;
            }
        case "b||B":
            {
                 msii=Integer.parseInt(msi);
                msii=3;
                break;
            }
        case "c||C":
            {
                msii=Integer.parseInt(msi);
                msii=2;
                break;
            }
        case "d||D":
            {
                msii=Integer.parseInt(msi);
                msii=1;
                break;
            }
        case "e||E":
            {
                msii=Integer.parseInt(msi);
                msii=4;
                break;
            }
        default:
            System.out.println("tidak ada");
            break;
    }

    System.out.println(+msii);
```

Comment: `case` does not work the way you think it does.

Comment: sorry im newbie , and i do not really understand how it is

Comment: `msi` is supposed to be "a", "b", "c", "d", or "e", yes?  How do you expect `Integer.parseInteger(msi)` to convert that?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare datatype for `msii`.
It must be declared as `int msii` globally or `int msii=Integer.parseInt(msi);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not include any stacktrace of the `Exception` you get, I'm going to assume you get the `NumberFormatException`

From oracle:

> public static int parseInt(String s)
>                       throws NumberFormatException
>   Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. **The characters in the string must all be decimal digits**, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.
>   Parameters:
>   s - a String containing the int representation to be parsed
>   Returns:
>   the integer value represented by the argument in decimal.
>   Throws:
>   NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

Note that I marked the line

> **The characters in the string must all be decimal digits**

This should already answer at least why you get an error.

**You are trying to parse non decimal characters**

We cant really help you more than that until you provide a more accurate description on what is it that you are trying to do.